# How to find largest surrounding value of a 2D list?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, parsing, math

You have a list like the one below

```
list =  [ 
        [1,7,1,5,6],
        [1,8,9,1,5],
        [1,1,10,1,5],
        [2,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

Starting in the middle of the list, how would you analyze the surrounding numbers and change your position to the position with the greatest values. So in this scenario the

```
arr[2][2] (10) -> arr[1][2] (9) -> arr[1][1] (8) -> arr[0][1] (7)
```

Meaning starting in the middle of the array how would you pick only the values

```
[8,9,1]
[1,10,1]
[1,1,1]
```

and then do the same thing for whichever position has the greatest value [9].

What I have thus far:

```
midLow=0
midHigh=0
rowLow=0
rowHigh = 0
# -- Columns -- 
evenOddCol = (len(arr)%2) # Find if there are even/off number of items in the list 
mid = (len(arr)/2) # Define Middle row 

if evenOddCol == 1: # If number of rows is odd, make no changes 
    mid = mid
else: # If number of rows is even, define the upper/lower list
    midLow = mid-1
    midHigh = mid
# -- Rows -- 
rowLen = (len(arr[1])) # Length of an arbitary row
evenOddRow = ((rowLen)%2) # Does row have an even/off number of elements 
rowMid = (rowLen/2) # Define the middle of the row 

if evenOddRow == 1: # If the number of rows is odd, make no changes
    rowMid = rowMid
else: # If the number of rows is even, define the upper/lower rows 
    rowLow = rowMid-1
    rowHigh = rowMid

# -- Logic --

return arr[mid][rowMid]
```

Which returns 10, the middle value of the 2d list array.

After returning the value of the middle, you would have to identify the highest surrounding value. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is the goal? This recursive function you seek, how does it terminate the recursion?

Comment: @pstatix The function would terminate when it gets to the edge of the array. Meaning any variable in the first/last row or column. Similar to a maze of finding the greatest values til you get to the end.

Comment: And it must always initialize in the center of the array?

Comment: And surely you need to handle the case we maximum values are all the options (i.e. all the same value around centroid)

Comment: @pstatix yes, that is correct. Right now, however, I was mainly just looking for an efficient method to analyze the surrounding values. It must always initialize to the center of the array, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The code requires some refactoring (especially expressions like a `v in visited`), but the output is exactly what you need.

If you change the values in `list` to None when you visit points, instead of accumulating the list of visited points, then you can delete `v in visited` checks.

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s; %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

list =  [
    [1,7,1,5,6],
    [1,8,9,1,5],
    [1,1,10,1,5],
    [2,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1]
]

size = Vector(5, 5)

# All possible directions
directions = [
    Vector(1, 0),  # right
    Vector(1, 1),  # right and down
    Vector(0, 1),  # down
    Vector(-1, 1),  # left and down
    Vector(-1, 0),  # left
    Vector(-1, -1),  # left and up
    Vector(0, -1),  # up
    Vector(1, -1),  # right and up
]

# Getting value of interesting point except visited points
def get_val(v, visited):
    # x and y are swapped because the first dimension of
    # list is "rows" and the second dimension is "columns"
    return list[v.y][v.x] if v not in visited and 0 <= v.x < size.x and 0 <= v.y < size.y else None

# Getting the greater direction except visited points
def get_greater_direction(pos, visited):
    dir = max(directions, key=lambda d: get_val(pos.add(d), visited))
    return None if pos.add(dir) in visited else dir


position = Vector(2, 2)
visited = []
while True:
    print(position)
    visited.append(position)
    greater_direction = get_greater_direction(position, visited)
    if greater_direction is None:
        print("The travel is ended!")
        break
    position = position.add(greater_direction)
```